# Slow down or rate-limit USB traffic on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb

I'm doing maintenance work on an application that communicates with a custom human input device over USB.  The application had a bug (now fixed) that caused intermittent issues when data arrived from the device too quickly.

I now want a way to slow down USB traffic, using a system setting or third party tool of some kind.  This will help us with testing, and act as a workaround until the next software release.  Does anyone know of any way to reduce the USB reporting speed?  I'm working with Windows 7 but would welcome suggestions for other versions as well.

Comment: I don't know if slowing down USB is a solution, but since it sounds like you are the programmer with access to the source code, can you make your program do a stop/wait/pause after every input? This way your application, even if bombarded with lots of input, will either ignore the subsequent incoming data until it is ready to work, or put the data in a queue, and work from the queue, rather than working directly with the input from the USB device? (And also this may be better off in StackOverflow?)

Comment: You are correct - I've put in a fix much like you describe, for Version B of our software.  However, some of our customers have Version A, and I would love to have a workaround for them in case any of them run into the bug before we release Version B.